# Dojo's custom event handling

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, dojo

I would like to know whats the best way to create a custom event in dojo.

For example, say i have an action or call to a server and when its response arrives i want to trigger an event. i tried using .emit(from on and evented ) and also dojo.connect.

initially it worked and it always works in chrome, but when it comes to FF and IE it doesnt trigger the event. I keep wondering whether the event was fired or whether i am failing in catching the event??

Please help! Stuck since many days without sleep!

Comment: You might want to consider using topic/publish for this. Rather than catching the event, you can just publish something and then have subscribers listen to that topic. That's how I would handle it.

Comment: Please post an example that demonstrates the problem you're having.  It sounds rather strange that it would be working only in Chrome.

Comment: @Ken I have a single DOM application, a object which is created is registered globally. when this emits an event, another js file needs to handle that. I will put up an example here.

Comment: @Layke Thanks for that. I will try that too and check if it helps.